# função para retornar o número inteiro

Tags: python, python-3.x

o que estou fazendo de errado na minha função?

```
num2 = float(input("digite um número não inteiro: "))
def arrend(numero):
    if num2 - math.floor(num2) < 0.5:
        numero = math.floor(num2)
        return numero
        return math.ceil(num2)
print("o número inteiro correspondente é: {}".format(arrend))
```

Answer (score 2):

Quando você está chamando sua função arrend, dentro do seu print, você não está passando o parametro que será usado. Há também um erro no seu retorno, sua identação está errada, desta forma, o segundo return está dentro do if, e nunca irá ser executado.

```
arrend(numero)
```

Neste caso, acho que você quer passar a váriavel num2 como parametro. Ficaria algo assim, arrumando o retorno também.

```
def arrend(numero):
    if num2 - math.floor(num2) < 0.5:
        numero = math.floor(num2)
        return numero
    return math.ceil(num2)
num2 = float(input("digite um número não inteiro: "))
print("o número inteiro correspondente é: {}".format(arrend(num2)))
```

Comment: oi @Vinicius Macelai ele só funcionou para math.floor mas não funcionou para o math.ceil

Comment: @MárcioFeitosa ele retorna apenas uma vez, então ela só faz o comando return numero, pra retornar os dois valores, olhe minha nova resposta.

Comment: Ele continua não retornando nada para o ceil e agora quando o número deveria ir para floor ele retorna os dois (floor e ceil)

Comment: Ah, entendi o seu problema, você queria que caso falhasse a condição do if, retornaria a o ceil, editei novamente,

Comment: Você foi o cara nessa...

Answer (score 0):

Para você utilizar as funções dos métodos `floor` e `ceil`, você tem que primeiramente importar os métodos.

Outra coisa, quando trabalhamos com `funções` devemos saber como `implementa-las`.

Observe logo abaixo a solução da questão...

```
from math import floor, ceil


def arrend(num2):
    if num2 - floor(num2) < 0.5:
        return floor(num2)
    return ceil(num2)


num = float(input("digite um número não inteiro: "))
print("o número inteiro correspondente é: {}".format(arrend(num)))
```

Observe que quando executamos este código recebemos a mensagem: `Digite um número não inteiro:` . Neste momento devemos digitar um número real e pressionar `enter`. Neste momento o valor capturado pelo input é passado como parâmetro para a função `arrend()`. Chegando lá, o bloco `if` irá verifica se `n - floor(num2) < 0.5`. Caso a verificação seja positiva o retorno da função será `floor(num2)`. Caso contrário, o retorno da função será `ceil(num2)`.